# bash: 369-1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "369-1")

Tags: bash, math, sed

I am getting this error in a calculation.

```
IdWin=$(xprop -root | awk '/_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW\(WINDOW\)/{print $NF}')
xabs=$(xwininfo -id $IdWin | grep "Absolute upper-left X:" | cut -d: -f2 | sed '/ /s///g')
echo "xabs="$xabs"!"
xabs=369!
x=$(($xabs-1))
bash: 369-1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "369-1")
```

Notice that I am using sed to strip spaces from the string containing the numbers I need. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sed '/ /s///g'` doesn't strip spaces, it checks is there is a space and the replaces nothing with nothing. Although spaces wouldn't make a difference since you don't quote your vars

Comment: i just copied your code, its works for me :3

Comment: I thought i had problems with spaces at some point, that is why I use sed.  @123: are you sure my sed command does not strips spaces? echo "1 23" | sed '/ /s///g' gives me "123"

Comment: @aless80 Sorry, yes it does, I forgot `//` matches the previous pattern which is `/ /`, you could rewrite as just `s/ //g` though.

Comment: Thank you. @tso: you are right, on another machine I have it works. I have a new installation and maybe I need some updates.

Comment: try compute x like this: `x=$(expr $xabs - $xrel)`

Comment: Why have the numbers changed?

Comment: ops, I just edited my example to make it more simple. xrel is not there anymore, I just use 1 for simplicity. sorry for the confusion. 
@tso: I get "expr: non-integer argument"

Comment: what does `xxd <( printf "%s" "$xabs")` return?

Comment: @123: 00000000: 1b5b 6d1b 5b4b 3336 39                   .[m.[K369

Comment: @aless80 theres the problem then... Do any of the commands produce coloured output?

Comment: @123: I found the command that causes the problem. I use aliases in .bashrc, and in my new installation I found the xde editor, so I wrote alias pluma='xde'. Then I uninstalled xde. For some reason that alias causes the error, lol! If you want to drop a quick answer i'll give you credits

Comment: @aless80 It's fine, probably better if you put the answer yourself as you know exactly what you did to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@123 solved my problem in the comments. @123 suggested to use xxd and make a hexdump:

```
terminal> xxd <( printf "%s" "$xabs")
00000000: 1b5b 6d1b 5b4b 3336 39 .[m.[K369
```

which points to a problem with colors. I inspected my aliases in $HOME/.bashrc and I found that this alias was causing the problem in my new installation (but not in my old ones):

```
'alias grep='grep --color=always -B 0 -A 0'
```

Removing this alias fixed the problem.